# Approximation in master equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, open-quantum-systems

Can someone explain to me how it works the fact that the nonzero part of the term to be neglected in the master equation for open systems can be absorbed into the Hamiltonian of the system as stated in [Physics behind assumptions in deduction of quantum master equation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/462886/physics-behind-assumptions-in-deduction-of-quantum-master-equation) ?